# Updating NSManagedObject subclass after updating data model

Tags: objective-c, core-data, xcode4

I had an original data model that was used to create NSManagedObject subclasses. I have now added custom code to these subclasses.

If you add new attributes to an existing entity, is there an easy way within Xcode 4.1/4.2 to update/add the new attributes to the existing classes.

The only way I can see at the moment is to create new subclasses then copy and paste the custom code, although this feels like it could be error prone.

I am in development at the moment, so I don't really care so much for the upgrade requirements of the data stores. Just the coding shortcuts.

Cheers.

Comment: checkout mogenerator. Does everything you want and more. Seriously, it's awesome and will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I do for this case. You have to do it only once, with no more work required for future changes to the data model.

I create separate `.h` and `.m` files for my `NSModeledObject` subclasses with a **category**. For an entity called, say, "Event", it would look like `Event+Helper.h` and start like this:

```
#import "Event.h"
@interface Event (Helper)
// declare your public methods
@end
```

Now, when you generate the new subclasses from the model, all of these will still work.

Comment: This is a great idea, however it didn't work for me as I have a couple of instance variables in my custom class. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I do not see how your condition precludes my solution. Rather I think it is very suitable for this purpose. Your custom variables will live in the category version of your modeled object subclass, which is just as good.

Comment: I would have thought the same thing. But Xcode and the compiler thought otherwise. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, I tried your suggestion. The compiler complained about ivars inside a category. As stated, I thought it was a good idea and obviously works for some situations just not when ivars are involved.

Comment: For reference the exact message from the compilers is:
Ivars may not be placed in categories

`#import "TestObject.h"`
``
`@interface TestObject (Test) {`
`    int ivartest;`
`}`
``
`@end`

Comment: OK, I did do this without ivars. However, in many cases you can replace ivars with methods. E.g. like `NSString *timeLeft = [event formattedRemainingTime]`. If you actually need to persist data, it should be in the data model anyway, i.e. an ivar in the original class. If you do not want to persist them, but just be able to assign them once you have the object, create an attribute and leave it empty.